# Maven ArtifactNotFoundException when downloading artefact from repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven-3, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-codeartifact

I have a AWS CodeArtifact repo that has a dependency. When I do the `mvn clean install -U` in a CICD pipeline, it appears to download the required dependency but then fails with a `ArtifactNotFoundException`.

output

> Downloading from my-domain-my-repository:
> https://my-domain-XXXXXXX.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-repository/com/travellinck/integration/travellinck-osgi-bom/1.0/travellinck-osgi-bom-1.0.pom

> [DEBUG] Writing tracking file
> /root/.m2/repository/com/travellinck/integration/travellinck-osgi-bom/1.0/travellinck-osgi-bom-1.0.pom.lastUpdated

Then it gets an error when trying to compile.

> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException:
> Failure to find
> com.travellinck.integration:travellinck-osgi-bom:pom:1.0 in
> https://my-domain-XXXXXXX.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/my-repository/
> was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
> until the update interval of my-domain-my-repository has elapsed or
> updates are forced

Do you know why it seems to download the artefact, but the fails with an error that it's not found?

Does this mean it has downloaded the artefact successfully?

> [DEBUG] Writing tracking file
> /root/.m2/repository/com/travellinck/integration/travellinck-osgi-bom/1.0/travellinck-osgi-bom-1.0.pom.lastUpdated